# Connecting to TFS 2008 and TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

Our company is currently using TFS 2008. We installed TFS 2012 on a different Windows server and restored all the team projects from the backup (TFS 2008). Then we upgraded to TFS 2013 on that Windows server. The URL to this new TFS server is also different. When we connect to TFS 2013 using VS 2012 (because we want the developers to UAT the changes), we cannot connect back to TFS 2008, and get this error:

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try cleaning up TFS client cache. You'll have to delete this folder:
`c:\Users\<account name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\` on the VS machines.